# Some Cordova plugin are undefined in iOS emulator

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using many cordova plugins, all of them works fine on Android, but not working on iOS. I'm building with cordova-ios 3.7.0, cordova CLI 4.1.2, iOS 7.0, 7.1, 8.0 on simulator. I've tried every tip I could find, like `cordova platform update ios`, re-add platform ios, re-add plugin, clean and rebuild in xcode.

I'm very sure `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` has included(It's visible from safari web inspector, and I can find `window.cordova` object), and all of my plugins are in the `cordova_plugins.js`. Any idea?

[edit]

Some example:

(cordova network-state plugin)
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.connection.type')`
I can find `navigator` object, but no prop `connection` in the object.
There are no `Connection` obj too, but I can see `network.js` and `connection.js` from safari web inspector resource.

The `deviceready` event not fired and no `window.device` object. But I can find `device.js` in resource too.

[edit]

Xcode build console:

```
2014-12-18 17:02:38.687 t2[87811:60b] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting.
2014-12-18 17:02:38.689 t2[87811:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-12-18 17:02:38.906 t2[87811:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-12-18 17:02:39.833 t2[87811:60b] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.059009ms
2014-12-18 17:02:40.471 t2[87811:60b] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 637.811959ms
2014-12-18 17:02:40.579 t2[87811:60b] [CDVTimer][file] 107.617974ms
2014-12-18 17:02:41.567 t2[87811:60b] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 987.930000ms
2014-12-18 17:02:41.568 t2[87811:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1735.188007ms
2014-12-18 17:02:41.948 t2[87811:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-12-18 17:02:43.176 t2[87811:60b] Finished load of: file:///Users/applesw2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*****/data/Applications/*****/t2.app/www/index.html#/app/file
```

Comment: How do you know plugins are undefined, do you test them after deviceready event? Perhaps you can share some code.

Comment: I tried them from safari web inspector console. Edited for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for future searchers. It's because one of my plugins broke `cordova.js`, so plugins included after the broken plugin not worked with js. I missed this error because safari web inspector doesn't have persist console log, so I can't see the err message happened before inspector opened.

Comment: This little comment save me some hours today, but it could be more specific. For anyone else coming here thinking that they might have a loaded plugin that breaks cordova.js, load your app in the iOS simulator, debug it in Safari, in the Safari console run window.location.reload() for the app to reload and see if you get any errors while your app is loading!

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because the functions not exists. Make sure you integrate `js` files inside `www` folder (cordova plugin repo) into your project.

Comment: Thank you, but I can find all js files from web inspector resource.